# Get all HTML attributes for a ASP.NET WebForms Control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, angularjs, webforms

Our application uses some custom controls, some of which has some fairly complex HTML output that gets generated.  We are now beginning to use AngularJS which make use of their own HTML attributes like `ng-hide=""` and `ng-show=""`.

I would like to be able to use these things in combination, as to prevent us from manually writing out all the HTML inside the control, maintain the intellisense for properties, and add additional `ng-*` properties on an as-needed basis.

Let's say I have a control called `button` and it has a bunch of custom properties on it.  I want to use it on an angular page like so:

```
<MyControl:Button runat="server" Text="Save" state="Success" ng-show="CanBeSaved()" ng-click="Save()" />
```

and it would output the following HTML

```
<button id="ctrl_1234" class="btn btn-success" ng-show="CanBeSaved()" ng-click="Save()">Save</button>
```

---

**Inside of the control, how do I get *all* of the attributes (even the ones this control has no knowledge of) and add just the angular-related ones?**

My first attempt/pseudo-code

```
Dim sb = New StringBuilder
Dim attrs = Me.Attributes.Keys

For Each a As String In attrs
    If a.StartsWith("ng-") Then
        sb.Append(" " + a)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: What's wrong with your attempt?

Comment: `Attributes.Keys` doesn't look like it returns what I was expecting, and it's not something that can be iterated over.

Comment: Do you still need an answer for this? Are you trying to get the collection of server-side properties like (ID, Visible, Text, MyNewProperty etc) or just the HTML attributes like (state, ng-show,etc?)

Comment: Yes to both. I want all the attributes that were written on the control when it was used.  The ones that are known properties will be handled already, but the problem is I am "making up" new properties/attributes as far as this control is concerned.  I'd like to just pass them through.

Answer (score 2):

I provided a simple function for Page_Load that will list out the ASP Properties & HTML Attributes if this will help you. I'm assuming that if you see these in iterate-able form it will solve your problem?

```
Public Sub PageLoad() Handles Me.Load

    ' source:
    ' http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.bindableattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

    ' Show server-side properties
    Dim attributes = System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(ControlID) ' Your Control ID
    For Each item As System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor In attributes

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Name=" & item.Name)
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Category=" & item.Category)

        ' You could only show certain category if you specify property categories like:
        ' <Category("MyCategory")> _

        If item.Category = "MyCategory" Then
        End If

    Next

    ' source:
    ' I used your existing code to iterate the collection & print
    ' SHow HTML attrs
    Dim attrs As System.Web.UI.AttributeCollection = ControlID.Attributes ' Your Control ID
    For Each a As String In attrs.Keys
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(a & "=" & attrs(a))
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Added fully qualified namespaces.